# Maven Jetty Run from Jar

Tags: maven, configuration, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

Here is want I want to do. I created a maven project and configured the jetty plugin for it in eclipse...

So from Eclipse if I do run and set the maven goal there to be `jetty:run` it runs my project in jetty on the port specified in web.xml. Now I want to build the jar file and when I do `java -jar myapp.jar` it will automatically call `jetty:run`.

How can I do this?

Comment: `jetty:run` is a **Maven** goal.  It compiles your project and then runs it in a Jetty container.  I don't understand the purpose of JARring the project first.  And _even if you did that_ `jetty:run` is not a standalone command.  It is command issued to Maven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to package your application so that you can hand it to someone and have them run it as a standalone application without having to go through deploying a war file into a web container, then that is a different concern from doing `mvn jetty:run` at development time, I will call that deployment time to avoid any confusion

At deployment time, we can't assume there will be maven on the machine, thus no `mvn jetty:run`, and even if there was, this would not work, unless we deliver the source code to run the build as in the development environment!

A standalone web application can be packaged by bundling the jetty jars in the application war along with a Main class to start jetty programmatically, and get it to run the application war. This relies on the fact that the file and directory structure of the WAR and JAR are different, and thus there is no significant overlap between the two, which is what makes this workaround possible, and it also leaves the option of deploying the war file in a web container possible

- There is a [maven plugin](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/winstone-maven-plugin/) that embeds [winstone](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/) which is another lightweight servlet container
- For jetty, you may start by reading [Embedded Jetty 7 webapp executable with Maven](http://open.bekk.no/embedded-jetty-7-webapp-executable-with-maven/)

Comment: Thanks .. The reason I am asking this is because I want to deploy the app on heroku. I mean do I deploy it using jetty run and then its started on their server. What happens if the application crashes during runtime? do I redeploy?